# Using thmutil extension in wix toolset

Tags: wix

I want to use elements defined in **thmutil** extension in wixtoolset but i can't find any dll file for this extension in wixtoolset directory. I am completely new to wix so can somebody help me with this problem?

Answer (score 1):

ThmUtil isn't an extension; it's a library for writing UI in C++ native code.

Comment: so how can i use the elements defined in this library?

Comment: Create an XML file that uses the elements to author a window then load it from C++ code.